# Commands under a cog not found

Tags: python, discord.py

When I made the cog and then did the help command in discord the commands under the cog didn’t show up

main.py

```
client.load_extension('cogs.commands’)
```

cogs/commands.py

```
class Commands(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
{commands}
```

Is there something I’m doing wrongly here? Thanks

Comment: It has this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.load_extension('cogs.commands')
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 676, in load_extension
    raise errors.ExtensionNotFound(name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.commands' could not be loaded.

Comment: I tried: 
`@client.event
async def on_ready():
  change_status.start()
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
  await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)
  print("Status set to online")
  await client.wait_until_ready()
  for filename in os.listdir("./cogs”):
        if filename.endswith(".py”):
            client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}”)`
But it also dosen’t work. There’s no error but when i use the help command the commands under the cog dont show up

Comment: It's better to include what you've tried/errors in your question with propper code block formatting. Reading code in comments can be a pain. Cheers.

Comment: Oops sorry, I’m new to stackoverflow . I’ll try to do that next time. Thank’s for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main.py

```
cogs = ["commands"]

if __name__ == "__main__": 
  for cog in cogs:
    client.load_extension(cog)
```